# Dealing with Unity's Remote Settings bug

Tags: unity-game-engine, service

I wanted to use the unity remote settings service and to my surprise, their own product was bugged. They managed to find a workaround by changing

public class RemoteSettingsLinker : IPreprocessBuild, IProcessScene

into

public class RemoteSettingsLinker : IPreprocessBuildWithReport, IProcessSceneWithReport

The errors stopped, but the value of the remote settings never arrived. I tried to print it to console and to a text field and both ways didn't work. When I choose the key in the remote settings I want to print it gives me this error:

Assertion failed on expression: 'ValidTRS()'
UnityEngine.Analytics.DriveablePropertyDrawer:DrawParam(Rect, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList:DoListElements(Rect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ReorderableList.cs:587)
UnityEditorInternal.ReorderableList:DoList(Rect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ReorderableList.cs:412)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Does someone know this error and managed to find a workaround or to solve it? Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way.
Turn on the Collaborate,and Download another PC,and connect the same projectID.
It seems to be repaired if it connects again.